# I try to create folders and name them after colum a in my sheet and at the same time copy a google docs document into the folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have use some codes form different youtubers where they show how it's works, but it don't work for me. hope someone can help me ehit my problem

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCUEW.png)

> function createFolderAndCloneGoogleDocument() {
>
> const foldermain = "1XjR90tuQMap1R0KUO2KUp04tDLxOdV4o";
> const fileID   = "1wBFVNEX88BgW2-98-w__SDmIxUT2wSlrmn7Vrd_pV4E";
>
> Spreadsheet Variables
> var ss = >SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QA4WXvBiNGcGsXmONHo1bm9E7Y9WGDXIoWQ-UjqDz1c/edit#gid=0");
> var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
> var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
>
> Google Drive Variables
> var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1QA4WXvBiNGcGsXmONHo1bm9E7Y9WGDXIoWQ-UjqDz1c");
>
> Logger.log(lastRow);
>
> for ( var i = 1; i < lastRow; i++ ) {
>
> create folder
> let kunde = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
> let column2 = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
> let column3 = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
> let column4 = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
> let column5 = sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
> if ( kunde != "Kunde") {
> var folderId = rootFolder.createFolder(kunde).getId();
> var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
> DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).moveTo(foldermain);
> Logger.log('Folder Name: ' + title + ' Folder ID ' + folderId);
>
> create Docoment
> var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldermain);
> DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).makeCopy(title,destFolder).getId;
> DriveApp.getFileById(docID).moveTo(folder);
> };
> }
> }

Comment: - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way and return with any other problems.  I have not tested it. So there probably are problems.

```
function createFolderAndCloneGoogleDocument() {
  const foldermain = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");;
  const fileID = "id";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");
  vs.forEach(a => {
    if (a != "Kunde") {
      var folderId = rootFolder.createFolder(a).getId();
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id"); 
      DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).moveTo(foldermain); 
      Logger.log('Folder Name: ' + title + ' Folder ID ' + folderId);
      var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldermain);
      DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).makeCopy(title, destFolder).getId;
      DriveApp.getFileById(docID).moveTo(folder);
    };
  })
}
```

Comment: it did not work here is the eror code
Exception: Invalid argument: parent.mimeType
(anonymous) @ Code.gs:11
createFolderAndCloneGoogleDocument @ Code.gs:9

Comment: I'm going to need to  see your data. Please note: - [I do not follow links to offset resources. Please provide data in a markdown table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/206484)